# Can I Use an OpenPGP Smart Card to Sign a TLS Certificate?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, smartcard, openpgp

I've been looking around for smart cards with support for Ed25519. More specifically, I'd like to have a TLS CA with the private key on a YubiKey. The latest YubiKey 5 supports secp256k1, secp384r1, and RSA 2048 in the PIV tool for storing TLS private keys/certificates, but it seems that the latest OpenPGP application [does support Ed25519 keys](https://developers.yubico.com/PGP/YubiKey_5.2.3_Enhancements_to_OpenPGP_3.4.html#_elliptic_curves) on version 5.2.3 and later.

So even though the PIV application does not support it, OpenPGP does.

I'm trying to build a self-signed CA for client TLS certificates, and I'd like the key for the CA to live in hardware on a YubiKey or another hardware device.

#### GnuPG Agent Commands

Upon connecting to the GnuPG Agent (via `gpg-connect-agent`), an interactive console is presented and the following commands exist:

```
# NOP
# CANCEL
# OPTION
# BYE
# AUTH
# RESET
# END
# HELP
# GETEVENTCOUNTER
# ISTRUSTED <hexstring_with_fingerprint>
# HAVEKEY <hexstrings_with_keygrips>
# KEYINFO [--[ssh-]list] [--data] [--ssh-fpr[=algo]] [--with-ssh] <keygrip>
# SIGKEY <hexstring_with_keygrip>
# SETKEY
# SETKEYDESC plus_percent_escaped_string
# SETHASH (--hash=<name>)|(<algonumber>) <hexstring>
# PKSIGN [<options>] [<cache_nonce>]
# PKDECRYPT [<options>]
# GENKEY [--no-protection] [--preset] [--timestamp=<isodate>]
# READKEY <hexstring_with_keygrip>
# GET_PASSPHRASE [--data] [--check] [--no-ask] [--repeat[=N]]
# PRESET_PASSPHRASE [--inquire] <string_or_keygrip> <timeout> [<hexstring>]
# CLEAR_PASSPHRASE [--mode=normal] <cache_id>
# GET_CONFIRMATION <description>
# LISTTRUSTED
# MARKTRUSTED <hexstring_with_fingerprint> <flag> <display_name>
# LEARN [--send] [--sendinfo] [--force]
# PASSWD [--cache-nonce=<c>] [--passwd-nonce=<s>] [--preset]
# INPUT
# OUTPUT
# SCD <commands to pass to the scdaemon>
# KEYWRAP_KEY [--clear] <mode>
# IMPORT_KEY [--unattended] [--force] [--timestamp=<isodate>]
# EXPORT_KEY [--cache-nonce=<nonce>] [--openpgp] <hexstring_with_keygrip>
# DELETE_KEY [--force|--stub-only] <hexstring_with_keygrip>
# GETVAL <key>
# PUTVAL <key> [<percent_escaped_value>]
# UPDATESTARTUPTTY
# KILLAGENT
# RELOADAGENT
# GETINFO <what>
# KEYTOCARD [--force] <hexstring_with_keygrip> <serialno> <id> <timestamp>
OK
```

#### Smart Card Daemon

By using the `SC help` command, we can also see what is possible by directly communicating with `scdaemon`:

```
> SCD help
# NOP
# CANCEL
# OPTION
# BYE
# AUTH
# RESET
# END
# HELP
# SERIALNO [--demand=<serialno>] [<apptype>]
# LEARN [--force] [--keypairinfo]
# READCERT <hexified_certid>|<keyid>
# READKEY [--advanced] <keyid>
# SETDATA [--append] <hexstring>
# PKSIGN [--hash=[rmd160|sha{1,224,256,384,512}|md5]] <hexified_id>
# PKAUTH <hexified_id>
# PKDECRYPT <hexified_id>
# INPUT
# OUTPUT
# GETATTR <name>
# SETATTR <name> <value> 
# WRITECERT <hexified_certid>
# WRITEKEY [--force] <keyid> 
# GENKEY [--force] [--timestamp=<isodate>] <no>
# RANDOM <nbytes>
# PASSWD [--reset] [--nullpin] [--clear] <chvno>
# CHECKPIN <idstr>
# LOCK [--wait]
# UNLOCK
# GETINFO <what>
# RESTART
# DISCONNECT
# APDU [--[dump-]atr] [--more] [--exlen[=N]] [hexstring]
# KILLSCD
OK
```

---

So, clearly, via `gpg-agent`'s `PKSIGN` and `scdaemon`'s `PKSIGN` commands, it *does* seem possible to sign arbitrary data, but I don't know if this is a direct signing operation or something unique to the OpenPGP specification.

I've done some [digging into OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/1aa08644ecd4005c0f55276b2e8dabd8a2a758f0/apps/x509.c#L879) to try to understand how exactly takes a CSR, signs parts of it, and creates a certificate from it. I'll probably have to do some more digging, but is there any way for me to use a low-level gpg-agent/scdaemon command to sign arbitrary data and somehow use this to sign the prepared certificate?

> By the way, I'm not just blindly choosing ed25519, I know that secp256k1 is roughly as secure, but in my particular case, performance is extremely critical in signing/verifying and every byte across the network counts for shipping cert chains.